# How to parse Javascript JSON array into ArrayList from Servlet

Tags: java, angularjs

I have an Angular JS function that sends a JSON array to a Java Servlet. With GSON class I am trying to parse that array back into an ArrayList of String (or another Class later). Unfortunately it looks like the ArrayList I get is null. Any suggestion?

EDIT: I forgot about request.getReader(), it works now.

Payload Sent:

```
{"answers":["answer1","answer2"]}
```

Angular JS Code:

```
    $scope.test = function() {
        var answers = [];
        answers.push('answer1');
        answers.push('answer2');
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/test', 
            data: { answers: answers }
        }).success(function(result) {
            // RESULT IS NULL
        }).error(function(result) {
        });
    };
```

Java Servlet Code:

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonElement jsonElement = gson.fromJson(request.getReader(), JsonElement.class);
    JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
    ArrayList<String> answers = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.get("answers").getAsJsonArray(), new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>(){}.getType());
```

Comment: You cannot use request.`getParameter` to get answers. Instead use `getReader`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `request.getParameter` to get the JSON message that you pass from Angular. Instead you have to use `request.getReader`

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject obj = (JsonObject) parser.parse(request.getReader());
```

Now JsonObject will have the message you sent. Now you can use this obj to convert it to an Array List.

Also in your Angular $http post, set the data to `answers` like this:

```
$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/test', 
            data: JSON.stringify(answers)
        }).success(function(result) {
            // RESULT IS NULL
```

After you have the JsonObject, you can use this to convert it into an ArrayList

```
ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<String>();     
JSONArray jArray = (JSONArray)jsonObject; 
if (jArray != null) { 
   for (int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){ 
    listdata.add(jArray.get(i).toString());
   } 
}
```

Comment: Yeah I forgot about request.getReader, now however I have another problem, I have edited the message above.

Comment: Ok. I have edited my answer to obtain an ArrayList as well.